# How can I make a desktop video and audio recorder in .NET, using .NET libraries?

Tags: c#, screen, video-capture

I need to make a project for my university. My project is a desktop video and audio recorder in C#... I know that I must use some of the libraries in .NET... But *which or how*?

It's like [Camtasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camtasia)...

Comment: @Frointi: There's no such thing as "C#.NET". There's C# and there's .NET and that's all. You may be thinking of VB.NET, where the two parts are in one word because there was a "VB" before VB.NET.

Comment: Oke. I'll make in C# Windows Form Appl..  And Im found, WMEncoder and WMPlayerSDK 9 for my project. But it seems to hard for me :( My teacher said that i must used to system.drawing.graphichs libs. And another I need get audio like Screen.

Answer (score 3):

There's at least one article on http://www.codeproject.com that shows how to do this:  [Capturing the Screen Image in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/cscapturescreen1.aspx)